# how to call stored function of IN and OUT parameter in Oracle Database using Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, function, package

```
public String getObjectDetails(String buffer) {
        dbcon con = new dbcon();        
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String name_msg=null;
        String type_msg=null;
        int type_code=0;
        int name_code=0;
        try {
            rs = con.dbstate().createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT pkg_test1.get_object_type('"+buffer+"',"+type_code+",'"+type_msg+"'),pkg_test1.get_object_name('"+buffer+"',"+name_code+",'"+name_msg+"') from dual");
            if (rs.next()) {
                return rs.getString(1) + "," + rs.getString(2);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(username.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return "";
    }
```

And, I'm trying to get information from these two function declared inside `PKG_TEST1` package

```
FUNCTION get_object_type(i_buffer IN VARCHAR2, o_errcode OUT NUMBER,
                           o_errmsg OUT VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2;

  FUNCTION get_object_name(i_buffer IN VARCHAR2, o_errcode OUT NUMBER,
                           o_errmsg OUT VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2;
```

But, I'm getting error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06572: Function GET_OBJECT_NAME has out arguments
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Calling stored procedures is different from executing SQL, please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html#calling_javadb_mysql You must register out params.

Comment: @home but this is not procedure, this is function and as far as i know,they are different.

Comment: Hm, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158212/call-an-oracle-function-from-java

Comment: Why you are putting out parameters in function, I think thats bad style. You should have used stored procedure. Functions generally make sense when you have all IN parameters, then function do some calculation on IN parameters and return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, thanks @home to suggesting me good link.

```
String call = "{ ? = call pkg_test1.get_object_type(?,?,?)}";
CallableStatement cstmt = con.dbstate().prepareCall(call);
 cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
cstmt.setString(2, buffer);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER);
cstmt.registerOutParameter(4, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
cstmt.executeQuery();
String type = cstmt.getString(1);
```

Well Explained Here : [**How to Call Strored Procedure and Function**](http://www.jweavers.com/posts/How_To_Call_Database_Stored_Function_And_Procedure_From_Java_Code.php)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    CallableStatement c = conn.prepareCall("{? = call get_object_type(?, ?)}");
    c.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
    c.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
    c.setString(2, buffer);
    c.execute();
    String res = c.getString(1);
    String err = c.getString(3);
```