# Oracle stored procedure an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Tags: oracle10g

I am having a stored procedure mentioned below.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE example(
    in_start_date IN VARCHAR2,
    in_svc_provider     IN a_message.msg_service_provider%type,sell OUT  number)
IS
BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*)   as sell
FROM a_message b1 WHERE TO_CHAR(b1.msg_when_created,'YYYY-MM-DD') = in_start_date
AND b1.msg_trans_type = 'SELL'
AND b1.msg_service_provider = in_svc_provider;

end;
```

While executing the stored procedure I am getting following error.

```
Error(11,1): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
```

Can you please provide me the resolution for this issue.while executing the same command in sql it is working fine but in stored procedure compilation error is occurring it means in stored procedure INTO replacing AS will give the same output please clarify.

Answer (score 4):

The error message is fairly self-explanatory; the [PL/SQL version of a `SELECT` requires an `INTO` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm) so the result of your query has somewhere to go. You already have an `OUT` parameter to put the value into:

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE example(
    in_start_date IN VARCHAR2,
    in_svc_provider IN a_message.msg_service_provider%type,
    sell OUT number)
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO sell
  FROM a_message b1
  WHERE TO_CHAR(b1.msg_when_created,'YYYY-MM-DD') = in_start_date
  AND b1.msg_trans_type = 'SELL'
  AND b1.msg_service_provider = in_svc_provider;
end;
```

The `SELECT` is now `INTO` your `OUT` parameter, and its value will be available to whoever calls your procedure.

This only works if your query will always return exactly one row. If it doesn't return anything then you'll get a no-data-found exception; if it returns more than one row you'll get a too-many-rows exception. And you need to have a variable for each column your query returns - only one in this case. You can also declare a local variable (between `IS` and `BEGIN`) to hold temporary values that you will manipulate within the procedure, but you don't need that here either.

When you compiled your procedure it would have said it compiled with warnings, because of that syntax error. If you created it in SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, and maybe some other tools, you could have seen the error straight away by issuing the command `show errors`, or at any time by querying the `user_errors` view. When you called the procedure it was invalid and was automatically recompiled, which just regenerated the same error as nothing had changed; that's when you saw the PLS-00428 message. It's better to look for errors at compile time than wait for recompilation at execution time.

Incidentally, it's generally better to convert a fixed value into the data type used by your table, rather than the other way round. When you do this:

```
  WHERE TO_CHAR(b1.msg_when_created,'YYYY-MM-DD') = in_start_date
```

... every column in your table has to have its `msg_when_created` `DATE` value converted to a string to be compared to the `in_start_date` string, which would prevent an index on that column being used. It's preferable to do:

```
  WHERE b1.msg_when_created = TO_DATE(in_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

or if your column has a time component:

```
  WHERE b1.msg_when_created >= TO_DATE(in_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND b1.msg_when_created < TO_DATE(in_start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

It would be even better to make your caller convert the value to a `DATE` so you don't have to worry about matching a passed format:

```
...
    in_start_date IN a_message.msg_when_created%TYPE,
...
  WHERE b1.msg_when_created >= TRUNC(in_start_date)
  AND b1.msg_when_created < TRUNC(in_start_date) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation I will try to make these changes as you mentioned, if any issue I will touch base with you.

Comment: can you please provide me the sample code for how to retrieve oracle number count using java callablestatemt.

Comment: @user3266456 - [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18842537/266304)? If you can't get that to work you should ask a new question showing what you've tried and what errors you get.

Comment: hi I tried this stored procedure called using java callabale statement

Comment: create or replace
PROCEDURE recon(
    in_start_date   IN VARCHAR2,
    in_svc_provider IN tra_message.msg_service_provider%type,
    total_sell_requests OUT NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
  -- Retrieve count of all messages from tra_message where trans_type is Sell
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO total_sell_requests
  FROM tra_message b1
  WHERE TO_CHAR(b1.msg_when_created,'YYYY-MM-DD') = in_start_date
 and  b1.msg_trans_type                           = 'SELL'
  and b1.msg_service_provider                     = in_svc_provider;
END;

Comment: I am getting value 0 for this stored procedure it needs to return 6.what might be the issue??please reply

Comment: @user3266456 - is your `in_start_date` in the same YYYY-MM-DD format (but see my comments about that!), and are you sure there is actually matching data for the values you pass in? If it isn't erroring then it looks like a parameter value problem, but really can't tell from here.

Answer (score 0):

use into function

example: `select count(*) into cnt_length from Table`