# An error, in select procedure? how to soleve this?

Tags: oracle, plsql

There is some mistake here and I do not understand how to solve it.

Comment: `53        SELECT naziv, kategorija, opis, komanda
 54        FROM zadaci 
 55        WHERE id = p_id;`

Comment: [Oracle stored procedure an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531670/oracle-stored-procedure-an-into-clause-is-expected-in-this-select-statement)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle stored procedure an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531670/oracle-stored-procedure-an-into-clause-is-expected-in-this-select-statement)

Answer (score 1):

What do you want the reporting procedure to do?

1. Display the values using `dbms_output`?
2. Return the values to the caller as `out` parameters?
3. Return a cursor?
4. Return a record to the caller?

I've coded all four below, and also improved the exception handling:

```
create or replace package utl_zadaci as

    procedure insertzadatak
        ( p_naziv      zadaci.naziv%type
        , p_kategorija zadaci.kategorija%type
        , p_opis       zadaci.opis%type
        , p_komanda    zadaci.komanda%type );

    procedure deletezadatak
        ( p_id zadaci.id%type );

    procedure modifyzadatak
        ( p_id         zadaci.id%type
        , p_naziv      zadaci.naziv%type
        , p_kategorija zadaci.kategorija%type
        , p_opis       zadaci.opis%type
        , p_komanda    zadaci.komanda%type );

    procedure displayzadatak
        ( p_id         zadaci.id%type
        , p_results    out sys_refcursor );

    procedure displayzadatak
        ( p_id         zadaci.id%type );

    procedure displayzadatak
        ( p_id         zadaci.id%type
        , p_naziv      out zadaci.naziv%type
        , p_kategorija out zadaci.kategorija%type
        , p_opis       out zadaci.opis%type
        , p_komanda    out zadaci.komanda%type );

    function displayzadatak
        ( p_id         zadaci.id%type )
        return zadaci%rowtype;

end utl_zadaci;
/

show errors

create or replace package body utl_zadaci as

    procedure insertzadatak
        ( p_naziv      zadaci.naziv%type
        , p_kategorija zadaci.kategorija%type
        , p_opis       zadaci.opis%type
        , p_komanda    zadaci.komanda%type )
    is
    begin
        insert into zadaci
            ( id
            , naziv
            , kategorija
            , opis
            , komanda )
        values
            ( seq_zadaci_id.nextval
            , p_naziv
            , p_kategorija
            , p_opis
            , p_komanda );

        commit;
    end insertzadatak;


    procedure deletezadatak
        ( p_id zadaci.id%type )
    is
    begin
        delete from zadaci where id = p_id;
        commit;
    end deletezadatak;


    procedure modifyzadatak
        ( p_id         zadaci.id%type
        , p_naziv      zadaci.naziv%type
        , p_kategorija zadaci.kategorija%type
        , p_opis       zadaci.opis%type
        , p_komanda    zadaci.komanda%type )
    is
    begin
        update zadaci
        set    naziv      = p_naziv
             , kategorija = p_kategorija
             , opis       = p_opis
             , komanda    = p_komanda
        where  id = p_id;

        commit;
    end modifyzadatak;


    procedure displayzadatak
        ( p_id         zadaci.id%type
        , p_results    out sys_refcursor )
    is
    begin
        open p_results for
            select naziv
                 , kategorija
                 , opis
                 , komanda
            from   zadaci
            where  id = p_id;
    end displayzadatak;


    procedure displayzadatak
        ( p_id         zadaci.id%type )
    is
        l_naziv      zadaci.naziv%type;
        l_kategorija zadaci.kategorija%type;
        l_opis       zadaci.opis%type;
        l_komanda    zadaci.komanda%type;
    begin
        select naziv
             , kategorija
             , opis
             , komanda
        into   l_naziv, l_kategorija, l_opis, l_komanda
        from   zadaci
        where  id = p_id;

        dbms_output.put_line('Podaci o zeljenom zadatku su:');
        dbms_output.put_line('Naziv:       ' || l_naziv);
        dbms_output.put_line('Kategorija:  ' || l_kategorija);
        dbms_output.put_line('Opis:        ' || l_opis);
        dbms_output.put_line('Komanda:     ' || l_komanda);
    exception
        when no_data_found then
            dbms_output.put_line('Trenutno nema nijednog zadatka!');
    end displayzadatak;


    procedure displayzadatak
        ( p_id         zadaci.id%type
        , p_naziv      out zadaci.naziv%type
        , p_kategorija out zadaci.kategorija%type
        , p_opis       out zadaci.opis%type
        , p_komanda    out zadaci.komanda%type )
    is
    begin
        select naziv
             , kategorija
             , opis
             , komanda
        into   p_naziv, p_kategorija, p_opis, p_komanda
        from   zadaci
        where  id = p_id;
    exception
        when no_data_found then
            dbms_output.put_line('Trenutno nema nijednog zadatka!');
    end displayzadatak;


    function displayzadatak
        ( p_id         zadaci.id%type )
        return zadaci%rowtype
    is
        l_zadaci zadaci%rowtype;
    begin
        select * into l_zadaci
        from   zadaci
        where  id = p_id;

        return l_zadaci;
    exception
        when no_data_found then
            dbms_output.put_line('Trenutno nema nijednog zadatka!');
            return l_zadaci;
    end displayzadatak;

end utl_zadaci;
/

show errors
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I have created, but I have a new mistake, you can look at it

Comment: If this doesn't answer your original question, can you explain why not?

Comment: How to call this procedure?

Comment: There are 6 procedures and a function. Which one? What isn't working?

Comment: There are 4 procedures, I used 2 exemple for the displayZadatak.
I do not know how to call them

Answer (score 0):

Petar,

There seems to be minor syntax errors in your code.

1. comma missing at line 25
2. additional bracket at line 44

I hope it helps.