# why registerOutParameter doesn't accept OracleTypes.VARCHAR?

Tags: java, oracle

i'm using spring jdbctemplate to get database data, and the store procedure that i want to retrieve results have input and output parameters.

I'm using the CallableStatement to pass this parameters in procedureCall, but when i specify some OracleTypes.VARCHAR, jdeveloper underline the expression.

```
CallableStatementCreator creator = new CallableStatementCreator(){
  String sql = "{call procedure(?,?)}";
  oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement cs = (oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement)connection.preparecall(sql);

   cs.setLong(1,10000);
   cs.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
   return cs;
}

return (MyObject)jdbcTemplate.execute(creator,new CallableStatementCallback(){
  public Object doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs) throws SQLException{
    cs.execute();

    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
    myObject.setMessage(cs.getString(1));
    return myObject;
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: should it be oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR? see similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158212/call-an-oracle-function-from-java

Answer (score 1):

I use eclipse with jdbc rather than JDeveloper and spring but have success with the following you might want to try.

Replace:

cs.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.VARCHAR);

with

cs.registerOutParameter(1,oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.VARCHAR);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe stab in the dark but:

```
cs.setLong(1,10000);
cs.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
```

both lines have same id of the attribute number