# Binding function call using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a jdbc preparedstatement using parameter binding

for example:

```
insert into CLOB_COLUMN values (?)
```

I would like to use empty_clob() and bind it to the parameter, then I can do something like

```
if(foo){
    statement.setClob("something");
else{
    statement.setfunction("empty_clob()")
}
```

Does JDBC support this? I feel like it is a common use case and I'm missing something. I don't see a way to bind a function to a parameter in the prepared statement and cannot find anything in the documentation, upon trying as a string it simply adds the string "empty_clob()" to the column in the row.

As a side note (for the specific use case but not the question, I know `statement.setClob(Clob.getEmptyClob()`) exists, does this actually activate `empty_clob()` under the sheets in oracle? Or is it making an empty clob object which has it's own location in tablespace, as opposed to pointing to the universal used in the function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call an Oracle function from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158212/call-an-oracle-function-from-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, JDBC does not support something like this. You can only set values using bind parameters, nothing else.

As to your second question: There is no `java.sql.Clob.getEmptyClob()`, so probably you are talking about the Oracle specific extension `oracle.sql.CLOB.getEmptyCLOB()` instead, whose documentation only says:

> Return a empty lob. An empty lob is used initialize a LOB column/attribute. Note: an empty lob can not be read or written

Note that this method is deprecated.