# How to call an oracle function with parameters from spring jdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, oracle-sqldeveloper, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

```
    public boolean deleteJobById(Long cplt_id, Long csco_id, Long cjob_id) {
//      String sql="SELECT PK_CP_JOBS.PF_DELETE_JOB(?,?,?) from dual";
    String sql = "call PK_CP_JOBS.PF_DELETE_JOB(?,?,?)";
    int res = this.jdbcTemplate.update(sql,cplt_id,csco_id,cjob_id);
    if( res > 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I've written this code to run an oracle function from spring jdbctemplate. Upon running i'm getting below error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
```

I've also written a test plsql block to test this function. It's running fine. 
Please anybody suggest me the way i can run this function.

plsql test code:

```
clear screen;
set serveroutput on;
declare
  n number :=0;
begin
   n := pk_cp_jobs.pf_delete_job(1,1022,17229);
   dbms_output.put_line(n);
   dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
  exception when others
   then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
end;
/
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158212/call-an-oracle-function-from-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call an Oracle function from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158212/call-an-oracle-function-from-java)

Comment: @kism3t I want to do that throught jdbcTemaplate and this funciton is performing DML operations.

Comment: Why not use `SimpleJdbcCall` as described in the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-simple-jdbc-call-1)?

Comment: @Andreas It has been implemented using SimpleJdbcCall. Thanks :)