# call an oracle function with array as parameter via hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

So i hava an oracle functiion like: `function unbind (ids in id_table)`. It takes an array of ids to perform some updates on my database.

The question is how can I run my function in order to perform update operations? 
What I've alreade tried:

1. `Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("call UNBIND(:ids)");
    query.setParameter("ids", myIds);
    query.executeUpdate();`

but I got ora-06576 not a valid function or procedure name

2. `Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("execute UNBIND(:ids)");
   query.setParameter("ids", myIds);
   query.executeUpdate();`

finish with ora-00900 invalid sql statement

3. `Long [] myArray = movedIds.toArray(new Long[movedIds.size()]);
   Boolean result = getSession().doReturningWork(new ReturningWork<Boolean>() {
     @Override
     public Boolean execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
       CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call UNBIND(:ids)");
       callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1,  Types.INTEGER);
       callableStatement.setArray(2, connection.createArrayOf("id_table", myArray));
       callableStatement.execute();
       return !(callableStatement.getInt(1) == 0);
     }
   });`

finishes with java.sql.sqlfeaturenotsupportedexception unsupported feature

The app conects to the database via jboss, so I suppose that could be the problem in p. 3?

4. `SELECT
   UNBIND( id_table    (6271789)    )  FROM DUAL` 
   does not work because my function performs updates...

Anyway is there any other method to run a function that takes an array as a parameter directly from java code?

Comment: May be refer to this :https://jsumon.wordpress.com/2009/12/27/call-oracle-function-from-java-program/

Make sure function UBIND exist in same user space as the one used for connecting to the database.

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple example, does this help?

```
import java.sql.*;


public class Class1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(  
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost/orcl","scott","tiger");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

        String query =  "{ ? = call test_func(?) }";
        CallableStatement cs = null;
        try {
            cs = conn.prepareCall(query);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int inVal = 0;

        cs.setInt(2, inVal);

        cs.registerOutParameter(1, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.NUMBER);

        cs.executeUpdate();

        int res = cs.getInt(1);

        System.out.println("result is " + res);
    }

}
```

Comment: this is not a procedure, but a function. I think you can not call a function via begin, can you?

Comment: oh my bad did you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158212/call-an-oracle-function-from-java I'll update my post