# How to use JPA or JDBC to call specific PL/SQL function using REF CURSOR

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

My problem is that I want to call PL/SQL function in @PostConstruct method in Spring Boot.

This function returns information about tables in a database as you can see above:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dbINFO
return sys_refcursor AS 
table_info sys_refcursor;
begin
    open table_info
        for select table_name from all_tables where owner = 'HOMEUSER';

        return table_info;
end;
```

I tried to use @NamedStoreProcedureQuery annotation but I don't have entity to use it with.
So I decided to try doing it with JDBC and so far I've got something like this.

```
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public HospitalApplication(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

@PostConstruct
    private void init() throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        EntityManagerFactoryInfo info = (EntityManagerFactoryInfo) entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
        Connection connection = info.getDataSource().getConnection();

        CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall("BEGIN dbINFO(); END;");
        stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        stmt.execute();
        ResultSet rs = ((OracleCallableStatement)stmt).getCursor(1);
        while (rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();

        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    }
```

Problem is, my program is throwing java.sqlException about column has incorrect index.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hospitalApplication': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect column index
```

***EDIT****

I tried something like that and I am receiving error:

```
PLS-00905: obiekt HOMEUSER.DBINFO is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

```
@PostConstruct
    private void init() throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n");
        EntityManagerFactoryInfo info = (EntityManagerFactoryInfo) entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
        Connection connection = Objects.requireNonNull(info.getDataSource()).getConnection();

        CallableStatement stmt = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call dbINFO()}");
        stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        stmt.execute();
        ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) stmt.getObject(1);
    while (rs.next()){
        System.out.println(rs.getCursorName());
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();

        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    }
```

Comment: Please edit the question and post complete error details, and which line of your code is the exception for.

Comment: `BEGIN dbInfo(); END;` is illegal in PL/SQL - you can't invoke a function without capturing its return value. IMO you're better off re-doing `dbInfo` as a `PROCEDURE` with an `OUT` parameter for the `SYS_REFCURSOR`. Then you can invoke it as `CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call demoSp(?)}");`

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica  The problem is It has to be a function. I want to capture return value but I don't  exactly know how I should do it.

Comment: [Does this question have answers which help you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158212/call-an-oracle-function-from-java)

Comment: Yup I also tried something like that but I receive error PLS-00905 HOMEUSER.DBINFO IS INVALID (take a look at EDIT)

Comment: Well then, your function may have an error. In any case it can't be called at present. Try executing `SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS WHERE NAME = 'DBINFO'`, find out what's wrong with your function, fix your DBINFO function, and try again. If there are no errors reported in the view for this function try compiling it again and see what happens.